# use loop to calculate basic sum in R

Tags: r, for-loop, sum

I set x=1:2,y=1:2，and I would like to display all x+y outcomes 2 3 4. But it just prints 2 and 4.

```
x<-0
for(y in 1:2){
  x<-x+1
  print(y+x)
}
# [1] 2
# [1] 4
```

Comment: You're running the body of the loop twice, and printing two values.

Comment: you need a nested loop, `for(y in 1:2) for(x in y:2) print(y+x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need all the combinations then use,

```
i<-0
abc <- array()
for(x in 1:2){
  for(y in 1:2){
     i <- i + 1
     abc[i] <- y+x
  }
}
```

If you need only unique combinatinos,

```
unique(abc)
```

Comment: While loops in R aren't necessarily bad, *growing objects* in a loop is slow.  You should pre-allocate the target instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want all combinations, you can do this with `outer` instead of an explicit loop:

```
x <- 1:2
y <- 1:2
outer(x, y, FUN='+')
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    2    3
## [2,]    3    4
```

You can then reduce this matrix to a vector with `c` and use `unique` to get unique entries:

```
unique(c(outer(x, y, FUN='+')))
## [1] 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `expand.grid` to get all combinations of x and y

```
dat <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
dat
  x y
1 1 1
2 2 1
3 1 2
4 2 2
```

And then calculate the sums with `rowSums`

```
rowSums(dat)
[1] 2 3 3 4
```

Or the unique `rowSums`

```
unique(rowSums(dat))
[1] 2 3 4
```